Regression table with model with re-specified standad errors
I am running models with plm with re-calculated standard errors. The challenge? I want to turn the models with the updated standards errors into a stargazer regression table.
Here is some sample data

library(plm)
library(stargazer)

df <- data.frame(year= rep(c(2000:2005), each=6),
                 county= rep(c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6"), times=6),
                 temperature= runif(36, min=40, max=80),
                 trade= runif(36, min=10, max=20),
                 policy.outcome= runif(36, min=0, max=100))

df.p <- pdata.frame(df, index=c("county", "year"))

m1 <- plm(policy.outcome
 ~ temperature + trade, data=df.p, model="within", effect="twoways")

summary(m1)

I would like to load this model into stargazer
summary(m1, vcov = function(x) vcovDC(x, type="HC1"))

stargazer(m1, align= T, type = "text")


What happens when you run your stargazer(m1, ...) code? Does it not return what you want, throw an error, etc?

help("stargazer") specifies how you can pass modified standard errors ...

As a side note modelsummary lets you do this in the same call with modelsummary(m1, vcov = \(x) vcovDC(x, type = 'HC1'))
